# Name This Sound Effect Style?

Tags: sound, effect

So the 'go to' effects for dream sequences etc are impacts, hits, stings, stingers, koto drums, drones etc.

But on a TV Programme I saw this kind of - mechanical whoosh which slows down.

Does anyone know what these are called? I'd like to get one similar but am unsure of what I'd search for. If they have a specific name then that could possibly lead to me getting more of differing types of whoosh and sound.

It's kind of like a slowed down flutter - but that won't really find me this effect!

Thanks for any help!

P.S I'm not talking about the heart monitor beep which is also occurring.

https://youtu.be/6fpOZbb5aFc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there is a Low Pass Filter that is automated from high to low frequencies. This will give the sound the muffled effect.

As for the slowing down part, time stretching or pitching the sound down will allow you to do this. It will take a bit to perfect the sound you want but is definitely achievable with the effects/processes mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, I took a flyby whoosh, put a filter on it, and gradually slowed it down. Sounds quite similar in nature after all. https://soundcloud.com/sonicaaron/flyby-synth-slow-down

Comment: It does sound similar! It reminds me of a vinyl slowing down